# PHP Execute CREATE TABLE mysql query many times

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have an **manage_db.php** file. All the database modifications during the programming, Ill update using the file. I will write the mysql queries and run in server.

If a CREATE TABLE query in the file and execute the file in many times, will be have any problem in the actual table (e.g.: aaa_test)?

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "
  CREATE TABLE `aaa_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  )
");
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a problem to have a create statement multiple times if you precede it with a "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".

So, in your case:

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aaa_test`;
>   CREATE TABLE `aaa_test` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `package_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>   );

Answer (score 1):

It's oke , it won't replace your current table, but it will produce warning, to prevent the warning (or possibly error ) you can just add `IF NOT EXISTS` (`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..`)

Comment: If the query run successfully, it will echo query in bold letters otherwise in grey letters. I have used CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, all the way in bold letters thats why Im thinking of change to CREATE TABLE

Comment: under some circumtances, the error could be fatal , so the IF NOT EXISTS will prevent re-creation of the table anyhow..